# flutter-iteration in widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

good afternoon, im new in flutter, and i have some problem in my code. how can i do n iterations. where n is snapshot.data.length. and this is the code I have.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Daftar Berita"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getBeritaDataAll("1"),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.error != null) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text("tidak ada koneksi, mohon periksa koneksi internet anda")
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    // Text("ada"),

                      listBerita(title: snapshot.data[0].title),
                      listBerita(title: snapshot.data[1].title),
                    // iteration till listBerita(title: snapshot.data[n].title),

                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three simple ways to iterate the `snapshot.data`

### 1st

```dart
for (var d in snapshot.data)
 listBerita(title: d.title)
```

### 2nd

```dart
 ...snapshot.data.map((e) => listBerita(title:e.title)).toList()
```

### 3rd

```dart
for (var i = 0; i <= snapshot.data.length; i++) 
 listBerita(title:testList[i].title)
```